# comes a little icon up over the image

Tags: html, css

I'm sitting and playing around with an idea about that when you hold the mouse over an image then there comes a little icon up over the image. I've tried to do like this:

**HTML:**

```
    <figure>
<div class="lukIMG">
<img src="/indhold/img/intet-nyhed-img/intet-img2.png" alt="fejl" style="width:339px;">
<img src="/indhold/img/sog/sog.png" class="iconIMG">
<p><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($dag));;?></p>
</div>
</figure>
```

**CSS:**

```
.lukIMG {
    position: relative;
}
.lukIMG p {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    right: 1px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #002855;
    color: #FFF;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
.lukIMG .iconIMG { position: absolute; display: none; }
```

**EIDT HTML AND CSS:**

HTML

```
    <div class="lukIMG">
    <img src="/indhold/img/intet-nyhed-img/intet-img2.png" alt="fejl" style="width:339px;" class="cl1">
    <img src="/indhold/img/sog/loading.gif" class="cl2" width="25px;" height="25px;">
    <p>dato</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .lukIMG {
    position: relative;
}
.lukIMG p {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: -4px;
    right: 1px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: #002855;
    color: #FFF;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
.cl1:hover+img
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:3;
}
.cl1
{
    z-index:2;
}
.cl2
{
    z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: @Radian The problem is that the icon does not appear when it is.

Comment: Check the fiddle I have given in my answer.

Comment: @RajeshPaul Check my **EIDT**

Comment: Checked. the icon image appears always. that's the problem. isn't it? Do you need a solution to that or something else?

Comment: What do you need now in your edit?

Comment: @RajeshPaul its Compelete now!! and thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uekVL/2/)** or the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        </script>

        <style>
            img
            {
                position:absolute;
            }
            img.cl1:hover+img
            {
                position:relative;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                z-index:3;
            }
            img.cl1
            {
                z-index:2;
            }
            img.cl2
            {
                z-index:1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="1.jpg" width=200 height=200 class="cl1"/>
        <img src='2.gif' class="cl2"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be work,please test it:

```
.lukIMG .iconIMG:hover { position: absolute; display: block; z-index:999}
```

add the code to your `css` file

Comment: http://billedeupload.dk/?v=dmW2O.png

Image not over the image as it should be know @radian

Comment: the better way is using one image as a background-image,and the second used to form,for more help please make jsfiddle